# Run C++ code easily on GPU lik Python language

Tags: c++, gpu

In order to run Python code with GPU (after installing all libraries for this), one can juste add these line before the code:

```
device_name= tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name!='/device:GPU:0':
    raise SystemEror('GPU device not found')
else:
    print('GPU found!')

with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
    #python code here...
```

Is there any similar way to run existing C++ code on GPU ? I've searched and I found that one should install other libraries and re-write the C++ code. I would prefer something (if exists) in a similar way of Python.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn’t have any facilities built in for GPU programming, you’d need to use something like OpenCL (or CUDA if you have an Nvidia GPU) for compute, or OpenGL/Vulkan or another graphics library for graphics.

Comment: There are some wrappers around CpenCL to try to make it easier: 
 https://streamhpc.com/knowledge/for-developers/opencl-wrappers/

Comment: @johnMastroberti, thank you for your response. Indeed, I have an Nvidia GPU. Hence, should I, re-written my code in Cuda format?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, thank you. Your proposition can work with Nvidia GPU?

Comment: OpenCL is an open format that works on all kinds of cards including NVIDIA. However you might get better performance out of CUDA code on an NVIDIA card (because they have their own compiler and also know their own hardware really well).